# how to refresh page every 5 seconds only current tab

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Hello** I have a project on xamarin, I use tabbed page and I refresh the page every 10 seconds like that

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), () => {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(new masterpage())));
            return true;
        });
```

but it works too slow and on every restart it goes back to first tab. How can i make it work in only current tab? or how can i make it work faster and correctly?

Comment: Probably inside ```masterpage``` you  have to start the same task to change only the tab you want for a star, then instead of pushing new views you just refresh the ones already created

Comment: actually i dont have any idea to how to do this

Comment: inside masterpage() there's somwhere you start a task to fill your tabs, you need to move the logic of refreshing to restart this task, you better yet if you do the task inside the tab instad of the masterpage

Comment: what do you mean by "refresh"?  Are you loading data from a service or database?  What kind of content does the page contain that needs to be refreshed?

Comment: Do you want to achieve the change background data, then data of view will changed immediatly? If so, you can use Mvvm and `INotifyPropertyChanged` to achieve it in xamarin forms. You can refer to this thread:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm